# Adding the elements of a BigDecimal Array in java

Tags: arrays, bigdecimal

I am new to Java and I came up to this error in my program where I can't add the elements in an array of BigDecimal elements. I successfully made it with Integer and Double types but when I change the type to BigDecimal, it won't work at all.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
public class AddBigRealNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{

        Scanner von = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of figures to be added:");
        int numfig;
        numfig = von.nextInt();
        BigDecimal []nums = new BigDecimal[numfig];

        System.out.println("Enter the elements:");

        for(int i=0; i<numfig;i++){
            nums[i]=von.nextBigDecimal();
        }
        System.out.println("The elements are: ");
        for(int i=0; i<numfig;i++){
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
        }
        BigDecimal sum=BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (BigDecimal i : nums)
            sum += i;
        System.out.println("The sume of these numbers is:"+sum);



    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Your exception is:" +e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Define "doesn't work at all". Does it not compile? If so, what error do you get? Does it throw an exception while running? Does it run but not produce the correct output?

Comment: Actually, it is just on the adding portion, but the others will still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add BigDecimal with `+`, you have to use its `add()` function. It is also immutable, so using the same BigDecimal sum for the whole addition won't work.

BigDecimal isn't just another class for numbers like Integer and Double are.

Answer (score 1):

> Because BigDecimal is immutable as LisaMM pointed out, you will need to increment your sum like so:

```
for (BigDecimal i : nums) {
        sum = sum.add(i);
}
```

...

```
sum.add(i);  <-- this wont't work
```

Instead we need to reassign a new BigDecimal to `sum` using its current value incremented by `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal sum = null;
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++) {
    if (sum == null) {
        sum = data[i];
    } else {
        sum = sum.add(data[i]);
    }
}
```